# What is the expected json autocomplete in textext plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm work with textext autocomplete via ajax.

This is the json I'm currently returning by my php but it doesn't seem to work:

[{"key":"2","value":"Arts & Entertainment"},{"key":"5","value":"Autos & Vehicles"}]

What type of json does textext expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It just returns a list such as:

[
    "Basic",
    "Closure",
    "Cobol",
    "Delphi",
    "Erlang"
]

so it's just an array of items in php that I needed to echo json_encode(array) and it worked.

hope this helps someone :)